# Query of a GUID field doesn't work entity framework and Oracle

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework-5

I have the latest version of Oracle Data Access Components (ODAC)  (12.1.0.1.0) and am using it with EF 5 database first.

in my data database i have a field of type RAW(16) 
When the data is saved into the database, the format is upper case without any dash (ex.: A0D8F7E720DDBF4296C932F7A730A635).

I try to query the entity with a where clause on this GUID field but cannot get any result. Our where clause looks like this (C#)

```
Context.Users.where(x=>x.GuidField == anotherGuid);
```

Both variable are GUID type.

The field GuidField is RAW(16) in the database but entity framework map it as GUID

anyone has any ideas.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

It seems to be a problem of the Oracle driver or ev. of how EF passes the Guid Parameter. The problem appears in where conditions when you compare two Guids (one raw(16) from the Oracle DB, one Guid in your program). It also appears in the Find() Operation when your entity has a raw(16) as a primary key.

After hours of wasted time I found the following, temporary workaround:
Make a Guid list, add the Guid you are searching for, then compare using list.Contains(). It seems as if in this particular case, the comparison is not done in the Oracle where condition on the database Server but in your .Net program. At least it gives the expected results.

e.g.

```
List<Guid> searchList = new List<Guid>();
searchList.Add(anotherGuid);
Context.Users.where(x => searchList.Contains(x.GuidField) );
```

Comment: The EF Query of the code sample above is: WHERE ( CAST('DC9CBA4616F41B42A38F75715F6A1554' AS RAW(16)) = "Extent1"."GuidField") while the Find and Where samples that don't work are using a p_linq_0 to pass the Parameter which you don't see in the query trace. Where is the bug, on EF or the Oracle side?

Comment: Hi GeoTask : i try your solution but my code looks like :    public TBL_USERS GetUserById(Guid userid)
        {
            List<Guid> searchList = new List<Guid>() { userid };            
            var user = DataContext.TBL_USERS.Where(x => searchList.Contains(x.PKID)).FirstOrDefault();
            return user;
        } But yet is returning null . do you have any other idea please. and thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

From the Oracle .NET team (via twitter @oracleDotNet) in response to my asking them to take a look at the thread: This sounds like bug 18336370, which is fixed in next ODAC release. Original bug described here: community.oracle.com/thread/3523194

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue using Oracle.ManagedDataAcess.dll Version 4.121.1.0. I couldn't find a better workaround as mentioned above. Very annoying issue, since GUIDs are in EF all over the place.

I am currently downloading ODTwithODAC121012.zip to check if the issue is still there. Hope to come forward with positive news.

**UPDATE 27.1.2015:**
I just checked the latest Version=4.121.2.0 Release 3 from Dezember 2014. The package was downloaded via nuget console. I still used EF 5 instead of EF6 for the test.
It is now possible to use a LINQ Expression with  EQUAL (=) and a GUID against a Oracle Database (Test Oracle 11 DB).
It was also possible to use lazy loading with foreign keys based on GUIDs.